# Rouge gem not showing line breaks in formatted code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rouge

I have followed minimal examples using the `rouge` gem [here](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge) (i.e. the documentation), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37721539/5783745) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57610845/rouge-gem-minimal-example-not-showing-formatting).

Everything working, except that line breaks in the code aren't appearing.

To be explicit, code like this

```rb
def plus_two(x)
  x + 2
end
```

has the colours highlighted correctly, but is rendered across one line, like so

```
def plus_two(x) x + 2 end
```

How can I make it render *with* the line breaks (just as in the code file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```rb
require 'rouge'
source = "def plus_two(x)\n  x + 2\nend"
formatter = Rouge::Formatters::HTML.new
lexer = Rouge::Lexers::R.new
@code = formatter.format(lexer.lex(source))
```

[image]

to

```rb
require 'rouge'
source = "def plus_two(x)\n  x + 2\nend"
formatter = Rouge::Formatters::HTML.new
formatter = Rouge::Formatters::HTMLLinewise.new(formatter, class: 'line-%i')
lexer = Rouge::Lexers::R.new
@code = formatter.format(lexer.lex(source))
```

[image]

More formatting options [here](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge)